# how to import csv file into sybaseASE with less columns than table field by using format file?

Tags: database, csv, unix, bcp

I'm using BCP to load data into SybaseASET table under UNIX

I have a `temp.csv` file with 4 columns:

```
name | id | attr1 | attr2
FIERA|20138||
SECOR|73328||
WELLINGTON|92413||
```

`template` table with two extra columns was defined like below:

```
create table  template
(name varchar(10),
 id int,
 attr1 varchar(5) default '',
 attr2 varhcar(5) default '',
 creation_time datetime null,
 active_flag char(1) null)
```

`bcp.fmt` format file:

```
10.0
7
1 SYBCHAR 0 10 "|" 1 name
2 SYBINT4 0 4 "|" 2 id
3 SYBCHAR 0 5 "|" 3 attr1
4 SYBCHAR 0 5 "|" 4 attr2
5 SYBDATETIME 0 8 "|" 0 creation_time
6 SYBCHAR 0 1 "|" 0 active_flag
7 SYBCHAR 0 10 "\r\n" 0 end
```

My purpose is to import all values include blank of temp.csv file into template table, leave the last two fields `creation_time` and `active_flag` as `null`.

I use command:

```
bcp client..template in temp.csv -F2 -f bcp.fmt -U -P -S
```

However, I always got the following error:

```
Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file. 
bcp copy in partially failed
```

I double checked my temp.csv file, all row terminator is `\r\n` as I listed in fromat file, why I still got unexpected EOF error?

Struggled too many times, all failed. Could anybody help me out? Thanks

===================update on Feb.06=================

Thank you James, I update format file to below as what you indicate:

```
10.0
6
1 SYBCHAR 0 0 "|" 5 creation_time
2 SYBCHAR 0 0 "|" 6 active_flag
3 SYBCHAR 0 10 "|" 1 name
4 SYBCHAR 0 4 "|" 2 id
5 SYBCHAR 0 5 "|" 3 attr1
6 SYBCHAR 0 5 "\r\n" 4 attr2
```

then I was prompt "Incorrect host-column number found in bcp format file"

===========================================================================

## ============SOLUTION IS HERE=============

first solution:

```
10.0
4
1 SYBCHAR 0 10 "|" 1 name
2 SYBCHAR 0 4 "|" 2 id
3 SYBCHAR 0 5 "|" 3 attr1
4 SYBCHAR 0 5 "\r\n" 4 attr2
```

second solution:

```
10.0
6
1 SYBCHAR 0 10 "|" 1 name
2 SYBCHAR 0 4 "|" 2 id
3 SYBCHAR 0 5 "|" 3 attr1
4 SYBCHAR 0 5 "\r\n" 4 attr2
5 SYBCHAR 0 0 "" 5 active_flag
6 SYBCHAR 0 0 "" 6 creation_time
```

Both work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your format file.

According to [Sybase documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1570/html/utilityguide/utilityguide86.htm), you should be using `SYBCHAR` exclusively:

> Host file datatype
>
> The host file datatype refers to the storage format of the field in
>   the *host data file*, not the datatype of the database table column.

The DBMS knows the datatype of its columns; it does not know how the input file is encoded.

Remember that the first element in the lines describing a column (3 onward) indicates the column in the *file*.  Your data file has no column 5-7.  I suspect that's the field provoking the error message.

Also afaik 0 is not a valid colid in the target table.  If you want to indicate NULL for a particular column, say it starts at the beginning and has no length,

```
1 SYBCHAR 0 0 "|" 7 active_flag
```

Finally, there's no need to account for the row-terminator in the format file.  You do that on the bcp command line with the `-r` option. If you're using Windows, IIRC that would become

```
bcp client..template in temp.csv -F2 -f bcp.fmt -r \r\n -U -P -S
```

In Linux of course you'd have to quote or escape the backslashes.

Edit: for clarity, here's what I think your file should look like,

```
10.0
6
1 SYBCHAR 0 0 "|" 5 creation_time
1 SYBCHAR 0 0 "|" 6 active_flag
1 SYBCHAR 0 10 "|" 1 name
2 SYBCHAR 0 4 "|" 2 id
3 SYBCHAR 0 5 "|" 3 attr1
4 SYBCHAR 0 5 "" 4 attr2
```

If that doesn't work, you'll have to find someone who, um, knows the answer.  I don't have a system handy to test on.

Nothing prevents any part of the data file from being mapped to many columns.  In field 1 of your format file, though, you mention data file columns 5 & 6, but your data file has only 4 columns.  I think that's what the error message it telling you.

> do you mean all datatype I put in format file should be 'SYBCHAR'

Yes.  The format file can describe text or binary files.  Your file is text, so all your data (in the file) are `SYBCHAR`.

Comment: thank you James, do you mean all datatype I put in format file should be 'SYBCHAR' no 'SYBINT4' Nor 'SYBDATAETIME'? I changed my format file like what you mentioned and also change the length to 0 for the extra columns in table, still got errors. please take a look for the detail in my above updated question. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to respond to your questions.  I hope that pushes you over the top.  :-)

Comment: It doesn't work. bcp format file is too trikcy.  Anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: although the problem about how to skipt two extra columns in table was not solved. You do help me figure out the bad data problem when bcp integer into table. Before I always use SYBINT4 in format file, even I don't have extra columns in table, the conversion is still wrong for integer part. This is another big trouble I didn't mention in this post. Now I understand why I can't get correct number in table from csv file, that's because of the difference between SYBCHAR and SYBINT4. James, you help me a lot. Thanks again

Comment: after try more times. I figure out how to skip table columns. We don't need put the extra columsn in format file, delete it, that's all. I edit my post to correct one. Nice to meet you here. I'm sooooo happy :)

Comment: Besides, I find second solution, it is very close to your answer, but we need do a little bit modification on your answer. then it will work properly